# How to connect the data retrieved from SQL database in activity method to luis intent and display the data using luis intent

Tags: c#, sql, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I want to connect the data retrieved from SQL database in activity method to luis intent and display the data using luis intent. What should I add in my Luis intent in SimpleLUISDialog.cs to display the data in database after I type in the utterances store in the luis intent?

And the activity method in MessagesController.cs is define by the MessagesController. Do I need to change the code in the activity method in order to suit the luisintent to work? The await context.PostAsync($""); in the luis intent need to be replace as i need to get the response from sql database. so i need to call the ShowCutOffPoint method into the luis intent. 
Thank you.

This is the activity method in SimpleLUISDialog.cs

```
  private async Task ShowCutOffPoint(IDialogContext context, 
  IMessageActivity msg, Activity activity)
    {
        // This method will take an Activity and return a response
        // that will conatin the current High Scores

        // Connect to the database
        Models.BotDataEntities2 DB = new Models.BotDataEntities2();



        var text = activity.Text;
        if (!Int32.TryParse(text, out int number))
        {
            //reply that there is no number;
            return;
        }
        // Get the top 5 high scores since yesterday
        var Courses = (from UserLog in DB.NYPCourses
                       where (UserLog.Course != null) && (UserLog.CutOffPoint == number)
                       select UserLog)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Course)
            .ToList();

        // Create a response
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        sb.Append("Course Information:\n\n");

        // Loop through each high score
        foreach (var Course in Courses)
        {
            // Add the High Score to the response
            sb.Append(String.Format("School: {0}/ Course: {1}/ Course Code: {2}/ Cut Off Point: {3})\n\n"
                , Course.School
                , Course.Course
                , Course.CourseCode
                , Course.CutOffPoint));
        }


        await context.PostAsync(sb.ToString());
        context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);

    }
```

Luis intent in SimpleLUISDialog.cs

```
[LuisIntent("CutOffPoint")]
        public async Task CutOffPoint(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> message, LuisResult result)
        {
        var msg = await message;
        await ShowCutOffPoint(msg);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move your `ShowCutOffPoint` method from the `MessagesController` to the `SimpleLUISDialog`.

Then update the signature of your `CutOffPoint` method to include the activity:

```
[LuisIntent("CutOffPoint")]
public async Task CutOffPoint(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> message, LuisResult result)
{
     var msg = await message;  
     await ShowCutOffPoint(msg) 
}
```

Finally, replace all the `ConnectorClient` related code

```
// Create a reply message
Activity replyToConversation = activity.CreateReply();
replyToConversation.Recipient = activity.From;
replyToConversation.Type = "message";
// Set the text containg the High Scores as the response
replyToConversation.Text = sb.ToString();

// Create a ConnectorClient and use it to send the reply message
 var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));

// Send the reply
connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(replyToConversation);
```

with

```
await context.PostAsync(sb.ToString());
context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
```

Comment: there is error which highlight the context in context.PostAsync(sb.ToString());
context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);

Comment: how to call the ShowCutOffPoint into my luis intent

Comment: an await was missing before the context.PostAsync(sb.ToString());

Comment: the await context.PostAsync($""); in the luis intent need to be replace as i need to get the response from sql database. so i need to call the ShowCutOffPoint method into the luis intent. Thank you

Comment: actually the await don't need to add as i forget to add in IDialogContext context in the method.

Comment: why after i add IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> message in the luis intent my emulator cannot connect to luis and did not show any response and post error- post 500 [message].

Comment: I don't know. What version of bot builder are u using?

Comment: my version of bot builder is 3.0.0

Comment: Thanks for all the help.After the update there is no more error but the bot emulator reply with a blank space with no word and no database retrieve after i type in the cut off point. Is it because you miss out something in the luis intent method as the await context.PostAsync($""); will show reponse that are blank after the utterances is type out. May be you miss out something that why the database is not retrieve.

Comment: I just copied you code. Call the ShowCutOffPoint from the intent method and that should make it

Comment: i have update my code above and there is error in await ShowCutOffPointAsync(msg); which highlight ShowCutOffPointAsync and the error is there is no argument to given that corresponds to the require formal parameter 'msg' of SimpleLUISDialog.ShowCutOffPointAsync(IDialogContext context, IMessageActivity msg, Activity activity). Thank you

Comment: These are basic programming questions tags you should resolve your self. Of course it fails. The method is not async.

Comment: if i remove the async in private async Task ShowCutOffPoint(IDialogContext context,  IMessageActivity msg, Activity activity). there will be error. the  await context.PostAsync(sb.ToString()); will show error.

Comment: You don't need to remove the async. You need to add it

Comment: what do you mean by the method is not async. Should i need to create another method call private Task ShowCutOffPoint(IMessageActivity msg)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }